# Perlbrew and libperl-dev

Tags: perl

I have Perl running under Perlbrew, meaning my local Perl is 5.24.0. However, I'm getting errors compiling some projects from source because my libperl-dev package is only 5.22.1. Are there any PPAs or repos that have a more up-to-date libperl-dev package?